# MSVC and GCC resulting in different code behavior

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++

I was solving a LC medium question in C working in visual studio. I compiled and ran my program with no issues, getting the expected output for all examples. I am using MSVC to compile my code.

I then copied my solution to the LeetCode IDE and am getting runtime errors every time. I went back to MSVC and enabled /Wall errors to catch everything, and worked to get rid of all errors or issues such that even /Wall shows no errors or warnings anywhere.

LC with GCC still isn't getting past the runtime error saying I have a buffer overrun.

Sorry for my messy code, I was adding more and more error checking even in places where it was not necessary.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find my issue, nor understand why two modern compilers will result in the first showing perfect behavior, and the second not even running.

Attached is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_LEN 20
char* flip_words(char* s);

int main(void)
{
    char* s = "  a good   example   \0";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    char* str = flip_words(s);
    printf("%s", str);
}

char* flip_words(char* s)
{
    //First need to clean spaces
    
    int len = (int)strlen(s) + 1;
    char* str = (char*)malloc(len);
    int offset = 0;

    //we want to copy all characters that are either not a space, or are a space that comes directly after a letter
    if (s[0] == ' ')
        offset++;
    else
        str[0] = s[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 && offset == 1)
            i = 0;
        if (s[i - 1 + offset] != ' ' || s[i + offset] != ' ')   //if letter is not space or previous letter is not space
        {
            str[i] = s[i + offset];
        }
        else
        {
            offset++;
            i--;
        }
            
    }

    //now we want to copy all words to an array of strings
    char** str_arr = (char**)calloc(sizeof(char*), len);
    if (str_arr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        str_arr[i] = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), WORD_LEN);
        if (str_arr[i] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    

    //tokenize sentence by separating words into strings in an array of strings
    int j = 0;
    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < len && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        k = 0;
        while (i < len && str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')  //copy letters until encountering space or NUL
        {
            str_arr[j][k] = str[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        if (k != 0)
        {
            str_arr[j][k] = '\0';
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    //count number of words in tokenized array
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str_arr[i][0] != '\0')
            j++;
    }
    j--;


    //start copying words from tokenized array to original array separating them with spaces
    k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        k = 0;
        if (j == -1 || i >= len - 1) break;
        while (i < (len - 1) && str_arr[j][k] != ' ' && str_arr[j][k] != '\0')
        {
            str[i] = str_arr[j][k];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        if (k != 0)
        {
            if (j != 0 && i < len - 1)
                str[i] = ' ';
            j--;
        }
    }

    //free strings in tokenized array
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        free(str_arr[i]);
    }
    free(str_arr);  //free tokenized array

    str[len - 1] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Note that in LC I don't have the main function, only the flip_words function and the #define statement.

P.S. Question asks to flip the order of all the words in a string and to return a string with the words flipped and all additional spaces removed.

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior due to a buffer overflow to me. https://godbolt.org/z/K53WGxa8s

Comment: @Phantom The code is awful because it is unclear.

Comment: @Phantom Pay attention to that the zero character in the string literal char* s = "  a good   example   \0"; does not make sense.

Comment: `s[i + offset]`. If `i` is `len - 1` (the highest value in the array and the highest youll reach in your loop) and `offset` is `1` (or bigger) you access elements out of bounds since the array is only `len` elements long and you try to access at `len`. Didn't continue after that so there might be some more errors.

Comment: @Phantom The array pointed to by str does not contain a string.

Comment: @Joel thank you for that, however, even after I change my loop to the following condition:
for (int i = 1; (i+offset) < len; i++)
I still get the same error.

I saw someone mention there is a buffer overrun, which is what GCC tells me, but I can't find it and neither can MSCV with WALL

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what do you mean the array pointed to by str does not contain a string? Sorry about the potentially silly question...

Comment: @Phantom It does not contain terminating zero character '\0'.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that  fixed it. THank you! I had the NUL character added at the end but it seemed to have liked it better when I added it right after copying the string in the beginning

Comment: @Phantom This function declaration char* flip_words(char* s) means that the original string must be changed. Otherwise the function should be declared like char* flip_words( const char* s ).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I thought I cannot modify string literals inside a function regardless no?

Comment: @Phantom It means that your function is declared incorrectly.

Comment: I see...I took the function declaration from Leetcode. Thats how they declared the function and I just wrote inside it.

Comment: @Phantom The approach with allocating memory for each word in the original string is inefficient, unsafe and bad.

Comment: Thought the [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ndbT4jb1o) version might be helpful for you.